# How to style ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST Android

Tags: android, styles, themes, spinner

I am trying to apply changes to the spinner.

```
SpinnerAdapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
```

I have been playing around with themes and looks like i need to apply this in order to make changes, however its not working. Am i using right parent for the SpinnerItem style? What am i missing?

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
</style>


 <style name="Spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@color/pending_red</item>
</style>
```

I inflate 2 different layouts in adapter, one in **public View getDropDownView** and another in **public View getView**

Doesnt look like android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item has any effect all.

***FOUND SOLUTION***

I had to use

```
 <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
```

instead of

```
 <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
```

in the root!

It was all **[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)** in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove

```
parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
```

and replace with this:

```
 <style name="Spinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/pending_red</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the right "parent", however its still not applying background colour. I traced it all the way to appcompat style and tried to change colors there but even that didnt work. Guess im missing something somewhere!

Comment: Maybe it's because you're setting the default `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` and it cannot be changed. Try to go for the custom one

Comment: That might have been the case, but ive realized i was using spinnerStyle, instead of actionDropDown!

Comment: If you have solved and my answer was helpful for you, set it as accepted